# Why can not NIFI start version control with REGISTRY?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

NIFI-1.10.0 and REGISTRY-0.5.0 is installed using DOCKER.
When the processor group upload the NIFI-Registry using hostname,geting the error as following,
[image]

```
WARN [NiFi Web Server-100] o.a.n.w.a.config.NiFiCoreExceptionMapper org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to obtain listing of buckets: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused). Returning Conflict response.
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to obtain listing of buckets: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a secured cluster (acces via https)? If so you need to give access to your nodes, like so (within the registry) :

[image]

If you are not in a secure cluster, try so set up an adresse like that : http://hostname:port . Without adding /nifi-registry

Another way to look, is within docker, be sure that your host can communicate with each others (Easier to be on the same docker network, and try to ping eachother)

Comment: Thanks.They can communicate with each others,and Nifi is installed in a stand-alone machine using secure mode.

Comment: BTW,Nifi and Registry use same keystore and truststore path

Comment: I am having same issue now after 3 years. Error : "Unable to obtain listing of buckets: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"  Both Nifi and registry (secure) are running on single macahine with 2 docker containers. both containers can ping each other. still buckets are not avaialble.  all permissions were given. localhost user created with proxy and read permissions in Nifi registry. still buckets are not available. Please help if any leads...